# Why cant I validate radio buttons when the groupname id is the same?

Tags: c#, html

I am trying to validate radio buttons. For example, if no radio button is selected, an error message will appear. My radio buttons include adding, multiplying, dividing, and subtracting. However, even though I put them in a groupname, when I try to enter them in a controltovalidate field, I am not able to.

Can you guys advice me in what I am doing wrong?

Thank you

```
<td class="auto-style3">
                <asp:RadioButton ID="radioAddition" runat="server" Text="Addition (+)" groupname="radiobutton" /><br />
                <asp:RadioButton ID="radioSubtraction" runat="server" Text="Subtraction (-)" groupname="radiobutton" /><br />
                <asp:RadioButton ID="radioMultiplication" runat="server" Text="Multiplication: (*)" groupname="radiobutton"/><br />
                <asp:RadioButton ID="radioDivision" runat="server" Text="Division (/)" groupname="radiobutton"/>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style4">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
```

Comment: No. That works fine. Its something that has to do with the RequiredFieldValidator. To simplify let me give you an example. Suppose I have a textbox and I dont want the textbox to be left blank. I would put a field validator in place. In the ControlToValidate box, I would then type "textbox" so that the validator knows what its checking.

Comment: google msdn how to use FieldVaildator for working examples

Comment: Heres an example of what I mean [SCREENSHOT](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByGkh3KXsrkmb3RtdUFneF9QWmc/view?usp=sharing) Notice the ControlToValidate box that I am talking about. I linked the radiobuttons by setting ControlToValidate =radiobutton but I cant figure out how to make it work